# How to display the days when there are no records in MariaDB?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following table called **employees**:

| employee | name |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | John |
| 102 | Alexandra |
| 103 | Ruth |

And the table called **records**:

| employee | assistance |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 2022-02-01 |
| 101 | 2022-02-02 |
| 101 | 2022-02-07 |

Let's suppose that I want to display the employee number, name and the days of the month in which there were absences between 2022-02-01 and 2022-02-07 (taking into account that days 05 and 06 are weekends). In that case, the result would be the following:

| employee | name | absence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | John | 4,5 |

How do I get that result?

So far I have developed a *query* where the days of the month in which there are attendances are displayed. Said *query* is as follows:

```
SELECT e.employee,
e.name,
r.assistance AS assistance,

OF employees and
JOIN LEFT(SELECT employee, GROUP_CONCAT(DIFFERENT EXTRACT(DAY SINCE assistance)
ORDER BY STATEMENT(DAY FROM assistance)) AS assistance FROM records
WHERE assistance BETWEEN '2022-02-01' AND '2022-02-07' GROUP BY employee) r ON e.employee = employee
WHERE (r.no_employee IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY name ASC
```

I would like to know how to implement the days in which there were absences and not consider the weekends. I've done several tests but I'm still stuck. I'm working with MariaDB 10.4.11

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth, 10.4.11-MariaDB

Comment: what is the "4.5" from?  isn't that supposed to be a number of days of absences?

Comment: @ysth, it was a typo. It is meant to be "4,5" (February 4th and February 5th).

Answer (score 1):

You use a recursive common table expression (requires mariadb 10.2+ or mysql 8) to get the list of dates in the date range, and join against that:

```
with recursive date_range as (
    select '2021-12-01' dt
    union all
    select dt + interval 1 day from date_range where dt < '2021-12-07'
)
select employee.employee, group_concat(day(date_range.dt) order by date_range.dt) faults
from date_range
cross join employee
left join records on records.employee=employee.employee and records.assistance=date_range.dt
where weekday(date_range.dt) < 5 and records.employee is null
group by employee.employee
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=5b16703e7310fc0eaeeb4090181d00f1)

If you are just looking for one employee, add that as a where condition.

Comment: If this is a common query or thera are others similar ones it may be worthwhile to create a calendar table. Attributes such as holiday can be encoded not only for weekends.

Comment: I got totally confused with the dates. I've updated the question, because the dates I mentioned being weekends weren't actually weekends.

Comment: ok, I don't think that makes any difference to my answer, though?

Comment: @ysth, no. It was for future readers